# Is it possible to reuse variable names with using namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, initially I have a sample program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a[3];
    sort(begin(a),end(a));
    cin;
}
```

Now I want to modify`std::cin`(to provide more functions like invoke a function when input fails). So I introduces a header`mystd.h` like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
//begin of mystd.h
namespace mystd {
    struct cin_wrapper {

    }cin;
}
//end of mystd.h
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a[3];
    sort(begin(a),end(a));
    mystd::cin;
}
```

But the change seems to be not convenient.(Users must mention all components `using std::sort;using mystd::cin;` or replace all `cin` with `mystd::cin`. `using namespace std;using mystd::cin;` causes the `cin` ambiguous)

In fact I'm going to write a modified standard library and make the use of it as convenient as the original one. The ideal code I wish users can write is:

(PS: this means `mystd` can be just used as `std`, not indicates I want to encourage users to use `using namespace` everywhere)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include "mystd.h"
using namespace mystd;
int main() {
    int a[3];
    sort(begin(a),end(a));//std::sort
    cin;//mystd::cin
}
//or
int main() {
    int a[3];
    mystd::sort(mystd::begin(a),mystd::end(a));//sort, begin, end from std
    mystd::cin;
}
```

I've tried to add `using namespace std;` in `mystd` but it also causes ambiguity.

One complicated solution I can image is to create a using statement like `using std::string;` in `mystd` for all std members not modified.

Is there a more practical way for me to implement `mystd.h`?

Comment: I suggest inside `mystd.h` you not have any `using std::` statements, and explicitly prefix the non-`mystd` identifiers with `std::` - anything else sounds chaotic and error-prone.

Comment: Writing code that encourages or even worst *expects* the widespread use of `using namespace X` is a bad idea.

Comment: I don't want to encourage `using namespace` usages, just want to provide identical usages to `std`. The namespace in the title is related to importing `std` members to `mystd`. Sorry for failing to express it clearly at first.

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on doing this, you *can* manage to do so by introducing your `using` statements at nested scopes. For example:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    using namespace mystd;

    int a[3];
    sort(begin(a), end(a));//std::sort
    cin_wrapper w;//mystd::cin
}
```

Anything involving `using namespace std;` should be avoided though (using other, more restricted namespaces isn't so bad, but that one is a huge truckload of cans of worms you're opening).

Comment: It seems `using namespace` in different scopes can't let me reuse the variable name `cin`, which means more changes will be required if switching from `std` to `mystd`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good idea, because it is very fragile.

Imagine that someone writes your "ideal" code.  Then, one day, you write `mystd::sort` that accepts a Range instead of two iterators.

Suddenly the meaning of the existing code has changed unexpectedly, and it starts to fail to compile because it wasn't anticipating that the number of parameters should now be one instead of two.

Comment: My modifications won't change existing functionality or interfaces of the functions. It will only influence some parameter checks, intermediate steps or the way of processing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is seamlesly implemented by the invention of "namespace".

If "productB" is your product with the same names as in "productA, you want to rewrite; then you decide, which names to be used by your users via some "using" statements in your interface file "productB.h" .

source file productA.h :

```
namespace productA
{
  void f1();
  void f2();
}
```

your source file productB.h : here you decide, what to use :

```
namespace productB
{
  void f1();
  void f2();
}
using productA::f1;
using productB::f2;
```

implementation:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include "productA.h"
#include "productB.h"

void productA::f1()  {  std::cout << "called A::f1" <<std::endl; }
void productA::f2()  {  std::cout << "called A::f2" <<std::endl; }
void productB::f1()  {  std::cout << "called B::f1" <<std::endl; }
void productB::f2()  {  std::cout << "called B::f2" <<std::endl; }
```

application: very convenient

```
#include "productA.h"
#include "productB.h"
int main () {
  f1();
  f2();
}
```

output:

```
called A::f1
called B::f2
```

notice: nothing is ambigous

Comment: I feel like you read the title, but not the text, of the question.